# C++: Terminate the project1 running in another project2 due to compilation of project1 has error but project2 is allowed to continue

Tags: c++, linux, windows, compilation

I am building a program1 to compile an external program2's code. How can I detect the failure of compilation and stop the compilation and yield the result that this program failed~~

so far my program1 is compiled as an executable program and inside it automatically invoke the command line to compiles the program2's code. but when the compilation has errors, the execution of program1 will be hanging.

Thanks~

Comment: Are you using `system` to call the commands?

Comment: You're reimplementing *make* or *Ant* or *Maven*. Why?

Comment: We need more information.  Most importantly, *why* does program1 hang when the compilation fails?

Comment: Yes I am using system()  command g++ xxxx and wait for a.exe, if a.exe is found then I will say it is successfully compiled.

Comment: You shouldn't need to wait.  When system() returns, the compilation *should* have either finished successfully or failed, unless G++ is doing something weird.

Comment: Hi Harry, how can I get to stop it running and get the flag of success or failure?

Comment: I think there is a run time error of my program1. that is why. i am debugging.

Comment: Typically, the return value of system() will indicate success (0) or failure (nonzero).  But it depends on the specific command that you're issuing.